# Order of Operations for echo statements

Tags: php

Here's my code:

```
<?php
    class Test_Class {
        public function Show() {
            return "Test_Class->Show() function";
        }
    }

    class Test_Class2 {
        public function Show() {
            echo "Test_Class2->Show() function";
        }
    }

    $var1 = new Test_Class();
    $var2 = new Test_Class2();

    echo "var1 :: " . $var1->Show() . "<br />";
    echo "var2 :: " . $var2->Show() . "<br />";
?>
```

Here's the output:

```
 var1 :: Test_Class->Show() function  
 Test_Class2->Show() functionvar2 ::
```

You'll notice that the class that **returns** the string has the result appear where it normally would, whereas the class that **echo's** the string has the result appear before the echo statement that it is called in.

Now, I know that it's getting processed first, and that's why it's appearing first.  But how does this look at a lower level?

It is something along the lines of:
.. parse
.. parse
.... Hey!  And echo statement, let's parse it!
...... Hey!  inside this echo statement that we're parsing is an object's method, let's parse that now
........ Inside this method there's an echo, so let's evaluate it
(output's inner echo statement)
....We finished evaluating the echo statement (output outer echo statement)
.. parse
.. parse

Is that close?

Anyone know the "order of operations" when it comes to this?

Comment: Yes, that's pretty much how it works. PHP won't actually echo anything until the string has been fully concatenated, which involves running the `Show` method. Since it encountered an echo inside that method, it outputs that immediately, even though the call seems to have appeared *after* the "outer" echo.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was thinking.  This seems like good sound reason for a method/function allowing to programmer to decide what to do with the result.  For example, simply returning the string instead of taking the liberty of echoing it.

Comment: Yeah, you hit the nail on the head. If possible, you usually want to minimize the amount of external effects a function has. Functional programming languages take this to an extreme with the idea of "pure" functions, or functions that have no side-effects whatsoever. A pure function called with the the same arguments will always return the same value, and does nothing else. This has the benefit of making it easier to reason about what a given function will actually do. So although PHP allows you to `echo` anywhere, it makes code easier to maintain if you do it as visibly as possible.

Comment: Congrats, You have 2013 reps now, happy new year 2013 :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's nothing to do with parsing.

`echo` needs an argument; it cannot be invoked until that argument is known.  In your second example, that argument is formed from two concatenation operations.  These operations must be performed before the argument is known.  Therefore, the arguments to these concatenation operations must be evaluated first.  So `$var2->Show()` is evaluated before any concatenation is performed.

Answer (score 5):

The string is concatenated during execution. The string must be built before it is echo'd.

**If you want the parts to be echoed left to right, use commas:**

```
echo "var1 :: ", $var1->Show() , "<br />";
echo "var2 :: " , $var2->Show() , "<br />";

/* output:

var1 :: Test_Class->Show() function
var2 :: Test_Class2->Show() function

*/
```

Comment: Wow.. I've been using `echo` for years, and yet I've never use it that way before.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Your order is pretty much right. Everything on the right hand side of the `echo` must be evaluated before the actual `echo` function is called. This means any `echo`s that are called from functions that your arguments call will be output first.